# Creating a table with R of two multiplied variables and the country names

Tags: r

So here's my code:

```
Gap <- read.xls(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
head(Gap)
tail(Gap)
attach(Gap)
summary(Gap$TotalPop)
summary(Gap$ChildMor)
#Median Child Mortality is 16.9 0-5 Child Deaths per 1,000 born
summary(Gap$GDP)
#Median GDP per capita in $PPP ()inflation adjusted) is $11,750
options(scipen=999)
print.table (c(Gap$GDP) * (Gap$TotalPop), Gap$Region)
```

What I need to do is print out 2 columns in the output, one GDP * TotalPop and one of the country name ("Region"). The issue is that for some reason, R is reading my Region names (which are letters) as numbers 1-144 rather than as their actual names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

```
product <- Gap$GDP * Gap$TotalPop
country <- Gap$Region

print(paste(c(product, country))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I need there to be two columns: one that says the name of the country and another saying the value from multiplying the two variables. The country names also just show up as numbers for some reason?

Comment: When I do print(country) it just lists the numbers as 1,2,3, 4, etc.

Comment: I figured it out using data.frame(). Thank you!